# LocalStack version 0.2.1 returning extra bytes in s3 get response

Tags: amazon-s3, junit4, localstack

We are using localstack version 0.1.21 to run unit tests in our project. It was workinig fine until end of 2019. It started showing below error whihle running test cases.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown port mapping for service. After googling for possible problems, we found below issue

https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1293

As suggested we upgraded to latest version(0.2.1). But now, We are facing another issue. s3 get is returning some extra bytes in response. It was working before upgrading. We have printed the response and found it prints 86  bytes(chunk signature). Previous vesrion byte size was zero.

Could you please explain if this is bug or I am missing some configuration

LocalstackTestRunner and Localstack are new files with 0.2.1, 0.1.21 had LocalstackDockerTestRunner and LocalstackDocker.

```
@RunWith(LocalstackTestRunner.class)
@LocalstackDockerProperties(randomizePorts = true, services = {"s3"})
public class S3Test{
private static final String BUCKET = "my-test-bucket";
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("awsS3Client")//it is created with default configuration using s3clientbuilder
    private AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("aws.client", "localstack");
        System.setProperty("aws.s3.endpoint", Localstack.INSTANCE.getEndpointS3());
        ...................
    }


    @Test
    public void test1() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        File file = Files.createTempFile("testfile", ".txt").toFile();
        String key = "testkey";
        amazonS3Client.putObject(BUCKET, key, file);
        S3Object value1 = amazonS3Client.getObject(BUCKET, key);
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(value1.getObjectContent());
        printResults(bytes);
        assertArrayEquals(com.google.common.io.Files.toByteArray(file), bytes);
    }

    private void printResults(byte [] arr) throws IOException {
        File file1 = new File("d:\\demo.txt");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file1);
        os.write(arr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("File contents: ");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Output on 0.2.1 : test fails with below assertion error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: array lengths differed, expected.length=0 actual.length=86
```

File contents:

```
0;chunk-signature=00fa94dcf5a419048a6cd61137dfdca2633bcfe528e508a80e98f97d5911a1fe
```

output on 0.1.21 is empty and test case passes. This is expected because file is empty file was saved in s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by setting chunkedEncodingDisabled property on AmazonS3ClientBuilder.
Below is the complete bean. referenced fields are standard beans

```
<bean id="amazonS3ClientBuilder" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder"
          factory-method="standard"
          p:endpointConfiguration-ref="s3EndpointConfig"
          p:pathStyleAccessEnabled="true"
          p:clientConfiguration-ref="awsClientConfiguration"
          p:chunkedEncodingDisabled="true"
    />
```